# Catching exception on failure to connect to server with WCF:

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I have a `Connection` class in my client application, which will connect to a WCF server.

If the server is not started, or for the client could not connect to the server, the exception should be caught and an error message is displayed on a label.

The first time I create an instance of the `Connection` class is here, in my `LoginViewModel` class:

```
sta = Connection.Instance.HttpProxy.Login(LoginID, LoginPassword);
```

and that is where the first exception is thrown. However, if I add a try/catch block, the exception will not be caught, but instead an `XamlParseException` is thrown instead. The try/catch block in the constructor of the `Connection` class will not work either. How do I handle this?

`Connection` class:

```
public sealed class Connection {

    private readonly string _address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionAddress"];
    private static Connection _instance;
    private static object _padLock = new Object();
    private static ChannelFactory<IPoS> httpFactory;

    private static IPoS _httpProxy; //Singleton
    public IPoS HttpProxy { get { return _httpProxy; } }

    public static Connection Instance {
        get {
            if (_instance == null) {
                lock (_padLock) {
                    if (_instance == null) {
                        _instance = new Connection();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Connection() {
        try {
            httpFactory = new ChannelFactory<IPoS>(
                new BasicHttpBinding(),
                new EndpointAddress(_address));
            _httpProxy = httpFactory.CreateChannel();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            BaseViewModel.SetErrorMessage("Error: " + ex, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown in the Login method because that is the first time the client will try to connect to the server. You can put the try catch arround this method, instead of the initialization. Besides that you should think about handling you connection class correctly, you connection is depending on disposable objects. When something is not working correctly, you have to call the dispose method. I do not thing making Singlton connection will handle all complexity, and error handling correctly if you access it multi threaded. There is no propper way to recover you channel if something is going wrong in a singelton situation.

Comment: I see. I'm actually just started learning about WCF. Do you have any links that I can read about on how to properly manage and make a connection to a WCF server?

Comment: Atleast you have to put using arround your HttpProxy classes. This will handle the dispose correctly. Normally I would recomment to build a new proxy on a user's action, and use it only for that action. This will avoid the handling of unexpected timeouts, faulted channels etc. The is not to much overhead in creating a new proxy class.